# How can I add Classes from a referenced C# Assembly to a ClassDiagram in my current project

Tags: c#-4.0, class-diagram

I have a referenced assembly that has a (devart) Linq Datacontext in it. We use this same assembly in a bunch of other projects and I don't want to add the source code to my current solution.

How can I add some of the classes in it to a ClassDiagram in my current project?

EDIT in Response to Comments/Answers

I don't have access to the original source code of the external project.

What I mean't was when I said "I don't want to add the source code to my current solution." was I don't want to build up a bunch of partials in my current solution either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a reference to the library in your project.
Go to the object browser (View->Object Browser) and search for your class.
Drag and drop it from the object browser onto the design surface.
I tried it with System.Random and it pulls all the properties and methods.

Comment: I don't have access to the original source code of the external project

Comment: That is just to help so you don't have to create the XML yourself.  You can create the XML for the class yourself and add it to the XML of the target diagram.